# verilog construct : expecting operand after case

Tags: case, verilog

Im currently doing a shift register for keypad (not sure if the term is correct though)

the actual plan is when people press each numbered keypad, the value of corresponding keypad will be stored into a register.

since user can only enter once at a clock cycle, shift register is needed so all the number can be cascaded together before transferring the input  to another module

the thing is, im facing an error stating

near text "case";  expecting an operand

this is the whole code for this specific module

```
input [3:0] key;
output [15:0] number;
reg [3:0] number0,number1,number2,number3;

always@(key)
begin
    for ( i=3 ; i>=0 ; i=i-1)
    begin
    {
        case(key)
            0   :   number[i] = 0;
            1   :   number[i] = 1;
            2   :   number[i] = 2;
            3   :   number[i] = 3;
            4   :   number[i] = 4;
            5   :   number[i] = 5;
            6   :   number[i] = 6;
            7   :   number[i] = 8;
            9   :   number[i] = 9;
            10  :   number[i] = 0;
            11  :   number[i] = 0;
            default:    number[i] = 4'bxxxx;
            number <= number[i];
        endcase
    }
    end
end
```

and the problem occur at the

case(key)

which im not sure why

"Curse those who vote this down for no research ! LOL"
nope, in fact, I researched a lot just that Im new on verilog and some parts are just difficult to be adapted without someone explaining (especially part where it run sequentially and part it run in parallel)

Comment: Not sure if it is related to the error, but number[i] is a bit, so you can't assign numbers to it as you do. `i` is undeclared as well. The test cases should take vector values rather than integers. And some other things, but first deal with these...

Comment: sorry for late reply, I didnt expect to get the fast respond through internet (im new to stackoverflow society). Yep, i notice the input declaration is indeed a silly mistake by me. I wondered why I wrote it like that. Reply from Unn clear up most of the doubts :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code you provided. The immediate problem is that you are using `{` and `}` to wrap your for loop like you might see in C or Java, but Verilog instead uses `begin` and `end` for creating code blocks. So, you need to remove those extra `{` and `}` characters (you already have `begin` and `end` in place to do the job).

Heres a few other things that aren't quite right for the design you described:

You need to declare `numberx` as an array, not as 4 separate variables. For example:

`reg [3:0] number0,number1,number2,number3;`

should be:

`reg [3:0] number[4];`

As such, the `number` output will need a new name (or the array will, one or the other).

Another thing that needs to be fixed is the actual shift register. As it stands now, there is no shift register. The line `number <= number[i];` is in the wrong place and will behave very differently than expected (ignoring the fact its in the case right now which is a syntax error unless Im missing something).

You need to define another `always` block that is clocked to implement your register. This block will need to shift in `number[0]`. Though, as it is a shift register, we no longer need the other elements of the array.

To clarify everything above, here is a simplified version of your module:

```
module keyShiftReg(clk, key, number);
  input clk; // We need a clock for the shift register
  input [3:0] key;
  output reg [15:0] number;
  reg [3:0] keyToNumber;

  always @(*) begin // While you are correct in saying @(key), in most cases, creating a sensitivity list is difficult and leads to mistakes, so use @(*) for combinational logic

    case (key)
      0   :   keyToNumber = 4'd0; // Always good to define the size
      1   :   keyToNumber = 4'd1;
      2   :   keyToNumber = 4'd2;
      3   :   keyToNumber = 4'd3;
      4   :   keyToNumber = 4'd4;
      5   :   keyToNumber = 4'd5;
      6   :   keyToNumber = 4'd6;
      7   :   keyToNumber = 4'd8;
      9   :   keyToNumber = 4'd9;
      10  :   keyToNumber = 4'd0;
      11  :   keyToNumber = 4'd0;
      default: keyToNumber = 4'bxxxx;
    endcase
  end

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    number <= {number[11:0], keyToNumber}; // Shift the lower 12 bits of the register up and insert the new value (keyToNumber) into the least significant 4 bits
  end

endmodule
```

Comment: Oh god, I think Im kind of understand how posedge work. Well, getting around it is driving me nuts but simple explanation from you solve this problem.

Im new to verilog and yes, most of the coding was written based on my experience on C, thou yes, I notice some silly mistake on the register part.

However, there's one thing bothering me now, doesn't this mean the clock need to be triggered ONLY when people set the input ? so the period wont be the same for each cycle doesnt it ?

"please dont answer it really directly, I want to try figuring it"

Comment: I was thinking that the clock on this part is not actually working as a clk, it will only trigger when there's input on the key

Comment: In your current system, you have no way of knowing when a new key comes in. If you know that the value of `key` cannot repeat, ie, `key` will never be 4'd1 and then 4'd1 again (two samples of 4'd1), you can use the change in value to detect when to load the shift register. Otherwise you need some sort of data valid or new data signal on for `key`. Even so, dont try to clock the shift register on this signal! Use a common clock and only load a new value in if the load is asserted.

Comment: validation for new data, that's what im looking for ! yes, i think i need to improvise the system a little, Using both clk and the validated signal to create the clk for shift register will do this, however, I am well aware some unnoticeable delay will occur.

Comment: Well, you dont actually want to clock the shift register on anything but a system clock. What you do is clock the shift register on a clock and use the data valid line as a shift signal to the register: `always @(posedge clk) begin if (data_valid) begin number <= {number[11:0, keyToNumber}; end end` (See how we only actually clock the register on the system clock, but use the data valid as a load/shift signal; all other edges where data valid is not asserted, the register retains its value)